# Parse an in-memory DOM?

Tags: html, dom, webkit, browser

I have done HTML parsing. I get a URL, and using Nokogiri I can extract components from the HTML. That is fine.

Now, I am wondering if the following it is possible or it just does not make sense at all:

When we look at a browser, there is a render engine that parses the HTML/CSS/JS and creates a visual representation of it. I am wondering if **it is possible to access that in-memory DOM interpretation**. So, for example, when parsing an HTML I can find a  that is pretty far from the root element, but when rendered it can appear on top of the page (because the CSS says it is absolutely positioned). I would like to be able to get that image as it appears on the browser.

Is there any open source API that would let me access this interpretation of an HTML file or what I am saying does not make sense at all, because what we see it is just that visual objects that can not be treated?

Comment: From what environment? The standard browser DOM API will tell you that.

Comment: It's just a visible result from applying CSS to the DOM.

Comment: @SLaks, I am willing to create a Ruby program that would let me parse a DOM as a user sees it, not as the HTML itself is organized.

Comment: @Barmar so, there is no "way" I could parse that programatically right?

Comment: @HommerSmith: So you want a rendering engine that finds the applied CSS properties for an element? Use PhantomJS.

Comment: @SLaks it's difficult to explain what I am exactly looking for. I think a web engine builds a list of objects, with a representation of, for example, a picture and where it sits on the page. This is what I would like to know. Because one of the things I would be interested is knowing which images are in top of the page.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Yes; that's exactly what a rendering engine does.  However, rendering engines are incredibly complicated; you shouldn't build one yourself.  Use PhantomJS.

Comment: SLaks I will take a look at PhantomJS and see if it is useful. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a *headless browser* – a rendering engine that works for your code instead of a user.
Look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).